# Parallel regression assumption on Imputed (MICE) Data with Brant Test in R

Tags: r, r-mice, ordinal

My data is ordinal, and so missing values are imputed with the polr method from the MICE package. Now I have multiple datasets which I can run an Ordinal Logistic Regression on. But, as the title mentioned: I want to perform a Brant test to check the parallel regression assumption. How can I perform such a test on my imputed datasets?

```
olr <- with(imputed, polr(target ~ var1+var2)) 
olrsummary <- summary(pool(olr))

> brant(olr)
Error in formula.default(model) : invalid formula
> brant(olrsummary)
Error in temp.data[, name] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I know I can take the first dataset with complete(imputed, 1) and use that for my Brant test. But that just don't sees right.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems more theoretical. Might be better suited for stats.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks. Asked it there aswell.